# SWT-App Loading .swf files from a runnable .jar or external folder

Tags: java, jar, flash, swt

I'm programming using the SWT Widget Library for Java in eclipse, and I'm designing a runnable Java application. I've got the application down, I just don't know how to load external .swf files from a folder on "ALL" computers. I can load Images from any computer, because I use the getResourceAsStream line of code. But the "import com.docuverse.swt.flash.FlashPlayer" "loadMovie(arg, arg)" only takes a String.

So I did ClassName.class.getResource("blah.swf").getPath();  which gives you a string, I set it up, and running it on eclipse it can perfectly find the file in the package. When I export it, the runnable Jar I made cannot find the "blah.swf" inside of the .jar file.

So there is my problem, how do I load my .swf files from within the .jar or from an external folder so clients can download along side the .jar executable application, so it can point to those swf files.

Thankyou.

Comment: If the SWT FlashPlayer is not capable of load movie from stream, you'll have to create temp file from the stream you get from jar and the load it by the player..

Comment: Well the stream outputs "file://C://Desktop//application.jar!//blah.swf" as you can see it tries to search inside of the application. I came up with a REAL dirty solution. I replaced "application.jar!" for the name of a folder I made on the desktop called "SWF". The thing is, if the application and SWF folder are in two different directories it wouldn't be able to find the path for SWF. But please elaborate on your comment, I'm quite confused with it.

Comment: Could you post link to `com.docuverse.swt.flash.FlashPlayer` jar file? I could not found any existing websites of the project.. Then I'll try to make [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Sure, here it is. http://www.actionscript.org/forums/attachment.php3?attachmentid=20786&d=1166994936

Comment: See my answer for possible solution, sorry that it takes a while, I was on conference ;]..

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way I talked about in comments (creating temp file and save flash animation from jar to it)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

import com.docuverse.swt.flash.FlashPlayer;

public class SWTFlashPlayer {
    private FlashPlayer player = null;

    private final String FLASH_FILE_PATH = "/EdnCateDance.swf";
    private final String TMP_FILE_PREFFIX = "tmp_";
    private final String TMP_FILE_SUFFIX = ".swf";

    private File swfFile = null;

    public SWTFlashPlayer() {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        try {
            swfFile = copyFileFromJar(FLASH_FILE_PATH, TMP_FILE_PREFFIX, TMP_FILE_SUFFIX);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        player = new FlashPlayer(shell, SWT.NONE);
        player.loadMovie(0, swfFile.getAbsolutePath());
        player.setSize(150, 150);
        player.activate();

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    /**
     * Copy file packed inside current jar to temp file
     * @param jarPath String - path inside jar
     * @param filePreffix String - temp file preffix
     * @param fileSuffix - temp file suffix
     * @throws IOException - temp file cannot be created or writing somehow fails
     */
    private File copyFileFromJar(String jarPath, String filePreffix, String fileSuffix) throws IOException {
        File toFile = File.createTempFile(filePreffix, fileSuffix);
        // delete file after application finishes
        toFile.deleteOnExit();

        if(!toFile.canWrite()) throw new IOException("File (" + toFile.getPath() + ") not exists or is not writable!");

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(toFile);
        InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(jarPath);

        if(is == null) throw new IOException("File on jar path could not be located or loaded!");

        int read = 0;
        byte bytes[] = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            fos.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }

        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

        return toFile;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SWTFlashPlayer();
    }
}
```

I used the EdnCateDance.swf flash file which is one of the examples in SWT Flash library.